# How to move Windows 10 Files to Flashdrive from a PC that doesn't boot

Tags: boot, data-recovery

My PC doesn't boot, autorepair and bootrec commands don't work, so I am trying to move files from this PC to a flashdrive, I only want to get an Excel sheet and 1 family picture, both are located on Desktop, is there a way to retrieve these files?

Comment: Remove your hard disk and place it in an enclosure or another PC.

Comment: Alternatively, boot an external system and mount your hard disc from there: you will need either an optical drive or a USB port for the bootable system, plus a separate USB port to plug in an external drive for the copied files, unless you can copy them on to your local network. You can use a Windows-based diagnostic disc, like [Hiren's Boot CD](https://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) or a Linux Live disc, like [Ubuntu Mate](http://ubuntu-mate.org/download/). The Hiren disc is getting quite old, so if you're happy to use Linux I would recommend this for more up-to-date file system support.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with the command line, then you could use the Windows Recovery Environment and copy them off from there (using command prompt copy command and possibly mounting using diskpart).

Or, you could use a Linux Live CD and accomplish the same thing-- you'll just need a flash drive (or an actual CD) that you can write the image to and boot off of.

Comment: Why was this down voted?  This is a very legitimate way to copy files from a dead system...